# Remove lines from a text file where columns getting repeated ubuntu

Tags: bash, text, duplicates

I have a text file like below.

```
1 1223 abc
2 4234 weroi
0 3234 omsder
1 1111 abc 
2 6666 weroi
```

I want to have unique values for the column 3. So I want to have the below file.

```
1 1223 abc
2 4234 weroi
0 3234 omsder
```

Can I do this using some basic commands in Linux? without using Java or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with some `awk` scripting. Here is a piece of code I came up with to address your problem :

```
awk 'BEGIN {col=3; sep=" "; forbidden=sep} {if (match(forbidden, sep $col sep) == 0) {forbidden=forbidden $col sep; print $0}}' input.file
```

The `BEGIN` keyword declares the `forbidden` string, which is used to monitor the 3rd column values. Then, the `match` keyword check if the 3rd column of the current line contains any `forbidden` value. If not, it adds the content of the column to the `forbidden` list and print the whole line.

Here, `sep=" "` instantiate the separator. We use `sep` between each `forbidden` value in order to avoid words created by putting several values next to one another. For instance :

```
1 1111 ta
2 2222 to
3 3333 t
4 4444 tato
```

In this case, without a separator, `t` and `tato` would be considered a `forbidden` value. We use " " as a separator as it is used by default to separate each column, thus a column cannot include a space in its name.

Note that if you want to change the number of the column in which you need to remove duplicate, just adapt `col=3` with the number of the column you need (0 for the whole line, 1 for the first column, 2 for the second, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the input but for my above file it doesn't remove duplicates. I get the below output for my file. '1 1223 abc,
2 4234 weroi,
0 3234 omsder, 
1 1111 abc'. Here '1 1111 abc' should also be removed.

Comment: @KillBill I believe you made a mistake copying my code :) You have to write `BEGIN {forbidden=" "}` : `forbidden` must be initialized with your separator (in this case, an empty space), otherwise the first line will never be matched (as we look for the **" "$3" "** pattern in our forbidden string)